# How to correctly cast a class to an abstract class when using type generics?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

I have the following classes

```
public abstract class BaseViewPresenter { }
public abstract class BaseView<T> : UserControl
    where T : BaseViewPresenter { }

public class LoginPresenter : BaseViewPresenter { }
public partial class LoginView : BaseView<LoginPresenter> {  }
```

I have a method that looks like this (simplified)

```
public BaseView<BaseViewPresenter> Resolve(BaseViewPresenter model)
{
    var type = model.GetType();
    var viewType = _dataTemplates[type];

    // Correctly creates BaseView object
    var control = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);

    // Fails to cast as BaseView<BaseViewPresenter> so returns null
    return control as BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>;
}
```

When I call this using an instances of LoginPresenter

```
var login = new LoginPresenter();
var ctl = Resolve(login);
```

The line `Activator.CreateInstance(viewType)` correctly resolves into a new instances of my `LoginView`, however `control as BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>` can't do the cast correctly so returns `null`.

Is there a way to correctly cast the `control` into `BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>` without using specific type generics?

Since `LoginView` inherits from `BaseView<LoginPresenter>`, and `LoginPresenter` inherits from `BaseViewPresenter`, I would assume there's a way to convert `LoginView` to `BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>`.

I am stuck with using .Net 3.5

Comment: Could you use in interface instead of an abstract class and mark `T` as covariant? Otherwise this kind of cast is not allowed.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No I can't, I'm stuck with using .Net 3.5

Comment: You cannot correctly cast the control into `BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>` because it is a `BaseView<LoginPresenter>`

Comment: You might be able to get away with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210483/covariance-also-in-3-5-2-0 Is using a 4.0 compiler allowed?

Comment: @phoog But `LoginPresenter` is a `BaseViewPresenter`, so I would assume there is some way of achieving this conversion. Am I incorrect in this?

Comment: @Rachel Yes, you are incorrect. Those casts are not allowed with generics unless the type is marked as covariant.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ugh, it's so obnoxious to go backwards in technology. Thank you :)

Comment: @Rachel This behavior would be no different in C# 5.0/.NET 4.5.  Classes have never been able to be covariant in C#.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This is a very frequently asked question. Let's rename your types:

```
abstract class Fruit { }                    // was BaseViewPresenter
abstract class FruitBowl<T> where T : Fruit // was BaseView
class Apple : Fruit { }                     // was LoginPresenter
class BowlOfApples : FruitBowl<Apple> {  }  // was LoginView
```

Your question now is:

> I have a `BowlOfApples`, which inherits from `FruitBowl<Apple>`. Why can I not use it as a `FruitBowl<Fruit>`? An apple is a fruit, so a bowl of apples is a bowl of fruit.

No, it isn't. **You can put a banana in a bowl of fruit, but you can't put a banana in a bowl of apples**, and therefore a bowl of apples is not a bowl of fruit. (And by similar argument, a bowl of fruit is not a bowl of apples either.) Since the operations you can legally perform on the two types are *different*, they cannot be *compatible*.

Here is a photo of StackOverflow legend Jon Skeet demonstrating this fact:

[image]

The feature you want is called *generic contravariance*, and it is supported only on *interfaces* and *delegate types* when the compiler can prove that the variance is safe, and when the varying type is a reference type. For example, you can use an `IEnumerable<Apple>` in a context where `IEnumerable<Fruit>` is needed because the compiler can verify that there is no way that you can put a `Banana` into a sequence of fruit.

Do a search on "C# covariance and contravariance" on this site or on the web and you'll find many more details about how this feature works. In particular, my series of articles on how we designed and implemented this feature in C# 4 starts here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: Thank you, your analogy of using fruit actually makes the problem a lot clearer to me :)

Comment: @Rachel: You are welcome! Jon Skeet usually uses bowls, fruit, apples and bananas when answering this question; I usually use cages, animals, giraffes and tigers, which is more exciting.  A paddock full of giraffes cannot be used as an animal cage because you could put a tiger into it, which would eat the giraffes. Which raises the question: would a tiger actually try to eat a giraffe? Giraffes kick pretty hard.

Comment: On the other hand, Jon can actually do a demonstration with fruit (see photo) and I cannot easily do so with giraffes.

Comment: @Rachel: One other thing: you have an intuitive understanding of the analogy, because the "generic type" in your mind that is "bowl of something" is very clear to you. The fact that the generic relationships in the business domain of your program are *not* immediately clear to you is evidence that you might not want to use generics for this purpose. I try to only use generics for cases where it is intuitively obvious what the generic type means. "baseview of some kind of presenter" is nowhere near as clear as "bowl of some kind of fruit", so maybe baseview shouldn't be generic at all.

Comment: @Rachel or maybe there is some subset of the baseview contract that (1) is what you actually need from the object returned and (2) does not need to be generic, while some implementation detail *does* need to be generic.  Then you can pull those members up into a base class or interface, and use that type as the return type of Resolve.  The more-derived generic type can have a reference to the specific type of view it is presenting without necessarily exposing it to the consumer of the method.

Comment: @Rachel for example, BaseView might have a method `EatThePresenter()` whose caller -- also the caller of Resolve -- does not need to know what presenter is being eaten, but the BaseView inheritor needs access to some property of the presenter to know how to eat it (i.e., does it first need to be peeled or sliced or... wait, did I say "presenter," I meant "fruit")

Comment: @phoog My ultimate goal is to make the `.Resolve` method assign `((BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>)control).DataContext = model`, and then return the `UserControl` object to be inserted in the UI.

Comment: @Rachel in that case you might be able to come up with something clever but it would probably be best to ask in a separate question.  But unless I were looking for an exercise in generics (which I often am), I would be very likely just to cast the DataContext in the property setter or a set method -- you are already casting the object returned from Activator.CreateInstance.  Casts are fairly cheap -- it's just a type check, really.

Comment: @phoog Thanks, I actually did end up doing something similar and posted my own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25795042/302677) :)

Comment: I just found this today and it is my new favorite answer on SO.

Comment: And all these answers do not address the  geographic distribution of tigers and giraffes.  They do not overlap ranges in nature.  What to do then?

Answer (score 12):

I accepted Eric's answer since it provides a great explanation of why what I wanted wasn't possible, but I also thought I'd share my solution in case anyone else runs into this same problem.

I removed the generic type parameter from my original `BaseView` class, and created a 2nd version of the `BaseView` class that included the generic type parameter and specifics for it.

The first version is used by my `.Resolve()` method or other code that doesn't care about the specific types, and the second version is used by any code that does care, such as the implentation of a `BaseView`

Here's an example of how my code ended up looking

```
// base classes
public abstract class BaseViewPresenter { }
public abstract class BaseView : UserControl 
{
    public BaseViewPresenter Presenter { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseView<T> : BaseView
    where T : BaseViewPresenter
{
    public new T Presenter
    {
        get { return base.Presenter as T; }
        set { base.Presenter = value; }
    }
}

// specific classes
public class LoginPresenter : BaseViewPresenter { }
public partial class LoginView : BaseView<LoginPresenter> 
{
     // Can now call things like Presenter.LoginPresenterMethod()
}

// updated .Resolve method used for obtaining UI object
public BaseView Resolve(BaseViewPresenter presenter)
{
    var type = model.GetType();
    var viewType = _dataTemplates[type];

    BaseView view = Activator.CreateInstance(viewType) as BaseView;
    view.Presenter = presenter;

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You could use an extension method to get the desired functionality from your original question. Just create the extension method as:

public static BaseView<T> Resolve<T>(this T presenter) where T: BaseViewPresenter

And then cast to BaseView<T> instead of BaseView.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon That won't work because I do not want to have to specify a specific type to use the `.Resolve` method. That's why my question specifies "without using specific type generics". Thank you though :)

Comment: If you used it in the same fashion as in your question (var  login = new LoginPresenter; var ctrl = LoginPresenter.Resolve();) then it would indeed work correctly and return a BaseView<LoginPresenter> - no generic specification necessary.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon Yes I'm sorry about that code sample, I used it for simplicity. In reality my `.Resolve()` method is called from the code-behind a custom `UserControl`, and the presenter passed into it is dynamic and unknown by the UserControl at the time it evalutes. All it cares about is it is of type `BaseViewPresenter`

Answer (score 3):

You're expecting to treat the type as being covariant with respect to the generic argument.  Classes can never be covariant; you'd need to use an interface rather than (or in addition to) an abstract class to make it covariant with respect to `T`.  You'd also need to be using C# 4.0.

Comment: `LoginView` does inherit from `BaseView<LoginPresenter>`, and `LoginPresenter` does inherit from `BaseViewPresenter`, so in theory I would assume that its possible to cast `LoginView` to `BaseView<BaseViewPresenter>`. You're saying that is not possible with 3.5 though?

Comment: @Rachel And that assumption would be incorrect.  The type would need to be covariant with respect to its generic argument for that to be valid.  Classes in C# are never covariant.  Interfaces have the *potential* to be covariant.  The syntax to support covariance for interfaces was added in C# 4.0.

Comment: +1. @Rachel - your expectation is simply unexpected. Relation between classes do not imply any relation between classes using them as generic's arguments. I.e. `List<Base>` and `List<Derived>` are siblings (have common base interface), but not derived from each other in any way. There are many posts on this topic - search for "C# covariance" (can add "Eric Lippert" for better results).

Answer (score 0):

My usual solution to this problem is to create an intermediary class that has access to the type-parametric class's methods through delegates. Fields can also be accessed through getters/setters.

The general pattern goes:

```cs
public abstract class Super {}

public abstract class MyAbstractType<T> where T : Super {
  public MyGeneralType AsGeneralType() {
    return MyGeneralType.Create(this);
  }

  // Depending on the context, an implicit cast operator might make things
  // look nicer, though it might be too subtle to some tastes.
  public static implicit operator MyGeneralType(MyAbstractType<T> t) {
    return MyGeneralType.Create(t);
  }

  public int field;

  public void MyMethod1() {}
  public void MyMethod2(int argument) {}
  public abstract bool MyMethod3(string argument);
}
```

```cs
public delegate T Getter<T>();
public delegate void Setter<T>(T value);

public delegate void MyMethod1Del();
public delegate void MyMethod2Del(int argument);
public delegate bool MyMethod3Del(string argument);

public class MyGeneralType {
  public Getter<int> FieldGetter;
  public Setter<int> FieldSetter;
  public MyMethod1Del MyMethod1;
  public MyMethod2Del MyMethod2;
  public MyMethod3Del MyMethod3;

  public static MyGeneralType Create<T>(MyAbstractType<T> t) where T : Super {
    var g = new MyGeneralType();
    g.FieldGetter = delegate { return t.field; };
    g.FieldSetter = value => { t.field = value; };
    g.MyMethod1 = t.MyMethod1;
    g.MyMethod2 = t.MyMethod2;
    g.MyMethod3 = t.MyMethod3;
    return g;
  }

  public int field {
    get { return FieldGetter(); }
    set { FieldSetter(value); }
  }
}
```

The above exemplifies getting all the methods and fields but normally I only need a few of them. This is a general solution to the problem and one could feasibly write a tool to generate these intermediary classes automatically, which I might at some point.

Try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLkmgR

Note that this is enough for all my cases, but you can be extra hacky with this:

```cs
public abstract class MyAbstractType<T> where T : Super {
  // ... Same everything else ...

  // data fields must become abstract getters/setters, unfortunate
  public abstract int field {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public static implicit operator MyAbstractType<Super>(MyAbstractType<T> t) {
    return MyGeneralType.Create(t);
  }
}

public class MyGeneralType : MyAbstractType<Super> {
  // ... same constructors and setter/getter
  //     fields but only keep method fields
  //     that contain the method references for
  //     implementations of abstract classes,
  //     and rename them not to clash with the
  //     actual method names ...
  public MyMethod3Del myMethod3Ref;
  
  // Implement abstract methods by calling the corresponding
  // method references.
  public override bool MyMethod3(string argument) {
    return myMethod3Ref(argument);
  }

  // Same getters/setters but with override keyword
  public override int field {
    get { return FieldGetter(); }
    set { FieldSetter(value); }
  }
}
```

And there you go, now you can literally cast a `MyAbstractType<Sub> where Sub : Super` to a `MyAbstractType<Super>`, although it's no longer the same object anymore, but it does retain the same methods and data, it's sort of a complex pointer.

```cs
public class Sub : Super {}
    
public class MySubType : MyAbstractType<Sub> {
  public int _field;
  public override int field {
    get { return _field; }
    set { _field = value; }
  }

  public override bool MyMethod3(string argument) {
    Console.WriteLine("hello " + argument);
    return argument == "world";
  }
}

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main() {
    MyAbstractType<Sub>   sub   = new MyAbstractType<Sub>();
    MyAbstractType<Super> super = sub;

    super.MyMethod3("hello"); // calls sub.MyMethod3();
    super.field = 10;  // sets sub.field
  }
}
```

This isn't as good in my opinion, the other version of `MyGeneralType` is a more straighforward layer over the concrete types, plus it doesn't require rewriting the data fields, but it does actually answer the question, technically. Try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S3r3ke

## Example

#### Using these abstract classes:

```cs
public abstract class Animal {
  public string name;

  public Animal(string name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public abstract string Sound();
}

public abstract class AnimalHouse<T> where T : Animal {
  List<T> animals;

  public AnimalHouse(T[] animals) {
    this.animals = animals.ToList();
  }

  public static implicit operator GeneralAnimalHouse(AnimalHouse<T> house) {
    return GeneralAnimalHouse.Create(house);
  }

  public List<string> HouseSounds() {
     return animals.Select(animal => animal.Sound()).ToList();
  }
}
```

#### We make this "general" variant:

```cs
public delegate List<string> HouseSoundsDel();

public class GeneralAnimalHouse {
  public HouseSoundsDel HouseSounds;

  public static GeneralAnimalHouse Create<T>(AnimalHouse<T> house) where T : Animal {
    var general = new GeneralAnimalHouse();
    general.HouseSounds = house.HouseSounds;
    return general;
  }
}
```

#### And finally with these inheritors:

```cs
public class Dog : Animal {
  public Dog(string name) : base(name) {}
  public override string Sound() {
    return name + ": woof";
  }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
  public Cat(string name) : base(name) {}
  public override string Sound() {
    return name + ": meow";
  }
}

public class DogHouse : AnimalHouse<Dog> {
  public DogHouse(params Dog[] dogs) : base(dogs) {}
}

public class CatHouse : AnimalHouse<Cat> {
  public CatHouse(params Cat[] cats) : base(cats) {}
}
```

#### We use it like this:

```cs
public class AnimalCity {
  List<GeneralAnimalHouse> houses;

  public AnimalCity(params GeneralAnimalHouse[] houses) {
    this.houses = houses.ToList();
  }

  public List<string> CitySounds() {
    var random = new Random();
    return houses.SelectMany(house => house.HouseSounds())
                 .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
                 .ToList();

  }
}
```

```cs
public class MainClass {
  public static void Main() {
    var fluffy   = new Cat("Fluffy");
    var miu      = new Cat("Miu");
    var snuffles = new Cat("Snuffles");

    var snoopy   = new Dog("Snoopy");
    var marley   = new Dog("Marley");
    var megan    = new Dog("Megan");

    var catHouse = new CatHouse(fluffy, miu, snuffles);
    var dogHouse = new DogHouse(snoopy, marley, megan);

    var animalCity = new AnimalCity(catHouse, dogHouse);

    foreach (var sound in animalCity.CitySounds()) {
      Console.WriteLine(sound);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Miu: meow
Snoopy: woof
Snuffles: meow
Fluffy: meow
Marley: woof
Megan: woof
```

Notes:

- I added names so it's clear that the method references carry their owner's data with them, for those unfamiliar with delegates.
- The required `using` statements for this code are `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, and `System.Linq`.
- You can try it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qkHL3#
- A version that makes `GeneralAnimalHouse` a subclass of `AnimalHouse<Animal>` can be found here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XS0ljg