# c# Upcast with generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting, abstract

I have defined an abstract class with an abstract constraint :

```
abstract class Asset<P> where P : Parm { }
abstract class Parm { }

class StockParm : Parm { }
class Stock : Asset<StockParm> { }

class BondParm : Parm { }
class Bond : Asset<BondParm> { }

List<Asset<Parm>> assets = new List<Asset<Parm>>();
Stock stock;
assets.Add(stock);
```

But I have received the error message:

> "Cannot convert type Stock to Asset"

Is there a way to list all the `assets`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly cast a class to an abstract class when using type generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792563/how-to-correctly-cast-a-class-to-an-abstract-class-when-using-type-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explain to the compiler that `Asset<Derived>` is `Asset<Base>`. The compiler compiles generic classes into deperate classes - one for each `T`. The name of telling the compiler that it is "ok" is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

MSDN:

> **Covariance** - Enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.
>   You can assign an instance of IEnumerable (IEnumerable(Of Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type IEnumerable.

Change `Asset<T>` to an interface and add the [`out` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

```
 interface Asset<out P> where P : Parm { }
```

---

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Asset<Parm>> assets = new List<Asset<Parm>>();
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        assets.Add(stock);
    }
}

public abstract class Parm { }
public class StockParm : Parm { }

public interface Asset<out P> where P : Parm { }    
public class Stock : Asset<StockParm> { }
```

Comment: I agree that interfaces would be useful here.

Comment: Keyword `out` denotes covariance, not contravariance - `in` keyword.

Comment: @kiziu - corrected my mistake + added like explaining the `out` keyword. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
List<Asset<StockParm>> assets = new List<Asset<StockParm>>();
```

Comment: No, he wants declare a List of `Asset Params` and then cast into an `Asset Param`, this is the tipical case of `Contravariant`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14030415)

Comment: @maazza Got it. Thanks!!