# How do you return a class that inherits a base class with a generic response?

Tags: c#, factory

I wasn't really sure how to phrase the question but hopefully this code will clarify the problem.

I have a base class like this:

```
public abstract class ServiceCall<TResponse> where TResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    // various properties
}
```

I have a concrete class like this:

```
public class TransactionRequest : ServiceCall<TransactionResponse>
{
    // various properties
}
```

TransactionResponse inherits from ServiceResponse

I have a few other request and response types that all inherit in the same way as the above.

These requests are mapped from a client that passes in a different request type such as:

```
 public InformationRequest : Request
 {
     // various properties to map to TransactionRequest
 }
```

I'm now trying to write a ServiceCall factory, where based on the information supplied by the client it will return the correct ServiceCall request.

So far I have this:

```
public class ServiceCallFactory
{
    public ServiceCallFactory()
    {
    }

    public ServiceCall<ServiceResponse> GetServiceCall(Request request)
    {
         ServiceCall<ServiceResponse> serviceCall;

         switch(request.GetType().Name)
         {
             case "InformationRequest":
               var transactionRequest = new TransactionRequest(request as InformationRequest);
               serviceCall = transactionRequest;
               break;

             // more cases
         }

         return serviceCall;
     }
}
```

However, this is complaining that I can't convert a TransactionRequest to a ServiceCall even though it inherits from ServiceCall where TransactionResponse inherits from ServiceResponse.

Ultimately, how can I create a factory with this current structure?

Comment: Have a read through answers for [How to correctly cast a class to an abstract class when using type generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792563/how-to-correctly-cast-a-class-to-an-abstract-class-when-using-type-generics) for a good explanation of why you can't do this.  There are also suggestions in the answers for ways to do what you want.

Comment: If possible, create 'IServiceCall<out T> ...'. Then use interface everywhere.