# Object oriented error

Tags: c#, .net

What is the reason for this code error:

> Casting Deriving Class as Base Class

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass<IComparable> baseClass;
        baseClass = DateTime.Now.Ticks == 100 ? new Age(110) :  new Name("behroz");

        Console.WriteLine(baseClass.Get());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : IComparable
{
    protected readonly T Data;

    protected BaseClass(T data) => Data = data;
    public abstract T Get();
}
public class Name : BaseClass<String>
{
    public Name(string data) : base(data) { }
    public override string Get() => "Name :" + Data;
}
public class Age : BaseClass<Int64>
{
    public Age(Int64 data) : base(data) { }
    public override Int64 Get() => 10 + Data;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why did you write the question 4 times? 2. What error? 3. Is `Casting Deriving Class as Base Class` a copy/paste of the error you get? (I doubt so)

Comment: I am not aware of the ObjectOrientedErrorException, they must have slipped that one in when i was not looking

Comment: Errors typically have error messages. The full type, message, and stack trace are essential for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the compiler. You should be getting this error:

> The type 'System.IComparable' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseClass'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.IComparable' to 'System.IComparable'.

That's you're first issue.

So you could change the `BaseClass<T>` to be this: `public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : IComparable`.

Bu now you have this error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Age' and 'Name'

That's because your `DateTime.Now.Ticks == 100 ? new Age(110) : new Name("behroz")` isn't making sure you're specifying a common type.

Now if I try to change it to `DateTime.Now.Ticks == 100 ? (BaseClass<IComparable>)new Age(110) : (BaseClass<IComparable>)new Name("behroz")` then I get these errors:

> Cannot convert type 'Age' to 'BaseClass'
>
> Cannot convert type 'Name' to 'BaseClass'

Now this is where it gets more interesting.

Just because `Int64` is an `IComparable` it **does not mean** that `BaseClass<Int64>` is a `BaseClass<IComparable>`. It's not.

Same with `BaseClass<String>` and `BaseClass<IComparable>`.

You simply can't use `BaseClass<IComparable>` for the types `Name` and `Age`.

Comment: Please read me again. I made a mistake

Comment: @behroz - What do you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132087/object-oriented-casting-error

Comment: @behroz - Did you read [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792782/259769)? (And did you go create a new user so that you could ask this question again?)

Comment: Eric Lippert solution does not solve my problem.

Comment: @behroz - It explains why your solution can't work. You have to find an alternative.

Comment: my goal  a solution or fix the problem

Comment: @behroz - What's the actual problem then?

Comment: I didnt understood why I cannot use BaseClass<IComparable>, considering string has implemented IComprable ...

Comment: @behroz - That's precisely what Eric Lippert addresses. Perhaps read it again? The whole fruit bowl analogy is very good.

Comment: @behroz - What was the underlying issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: i found  my answer and 
Where should i write?

Comment: @behroz - Add your own answer.

Comment: Where should i write?

Comment: @behroz - Sorry, it's been closed.

Comment: @behroz - Put it on https://dotnetfiddle.net and post a link here in the comments.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eexC7g

Answer (score -5):

You are trying to initiate abstract class, which is wrong.

BaseClass baseClass;

baseClass = new Age(110);

Casting deriving class(i.e. BaseClass) as base class is causing this issue.

You can directly call the class based on your conditions.