# object oriented Casting error

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, inheritance

**Casting Deriving Class as Base Class**

I have a base abstract class which is generic and inherits from IComparable which is defined like below

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : IComparable
{
    protected readonly T Data;

    protected BaseClass(T data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public abstract T Get();

}
```

Then I have defined a classe which inherits from this base class and has a specific generic type and is defined like below:

```
public class Name : BaseClass<String>
{
    public Name(string data) : base(data)
    {
    }

    public override string Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As generic type is string and string inherits from IComparable, I expect to be able to define new Name object with string value as generic type, but I get casting error for defining Name object like this:

```
BaseClass<IComparable> obj;
obj = new Name("behro0z");
```

and the error is

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type `ConsoleApplication1.Name`
>   to
>   `ConsoleApplication1.BaseClass<System.IComparable>`   ConsoleApplication1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a variable of type `BaseClass<T>`, and substitute `T` with `IComparable`.

That's valid, but that's *not* what your `Name` class is. That one derives from `BaseClass<string>`, **not** `BaseClass<IComparable>`, even though `string` implements `IComparable`.

You can either declare your variable `obj` to be of type `BaseClass<string>`, or the more derived type, `Name`.

Read up on covariance, [C# Generics Inheritance Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909209/c-sharp-generics-inheritance-problem).

Comment: I didnt understood why I cannot use BaseClass<IComparable>, considering string has implemented IComprable ?!!

Comment: @Majidkhalili - Did you read [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792782/259769)?