# Property base class is not valid return signature

Tags: c#

I thought that a base class would be an acceptable return signature but .Net Core 2.2 using visual studio code does not like it.

```
public class BasicRisk
{        
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Amount{get;set;}
}

public class LowRisk : BasicRisk
{
    public string Minimum { get; set; }
}

public class HighRisk : BasicRisk
{
    public string Risk { get; set; }
}
```

Now at some level this is working because I can mock populate data like this.

```
public class MockRiskkData
{
    private readonly List<HighRisk> _high = new List<HighRisk>();

    public MockRiskkData()
    {
       _all.Add(
            new HighRisk
            {
                Amount = "9384",
                Name = "Johnny Dangerous",
                Risk = "Extreme"
            }
        );
     }
}
```

However when I use the Baseclass as return value in a method signature I get can't explicitly convert error. Now my understanding was that any inherited class that uses the base class will satisfy the return signature.

```
public class MockRiskkData
{
    private readonly List<HighRisk> _high = new List<HighRisk>();
    private readonly List<LowRisk> _low = new List<LowRisk>();

    public MockRiskkData()
    {
       _all.Add(
            new HighRisk
            {
                Amount = "9384",
                Name = "Johnny Dangerous",
                Risk = "Extreme"
            }
        );
     }


    public Task<List<BasicRisk>> GetRiskAsync(int risktype)
    {
        if(risktype == 1)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_high); //Cannot implicitly convert type
        }

        return Task.FromResult(_low); //Cannot implicitly convert type
    }

}
```

So clearly I am incorrect in my understanding. What can I try next?

Comment: Might be the same issue but I removed the task wrapper and tried just a List<T> and same issue.

Comment: Same issue.  It's described in the accepted answer of linked question.

Comment: [A `List<Derived>` can't be implicitly converted to a `List<Base>`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792563/how-to-correctly-cast-a-class-to-an-abstract-class-when-using-type-generics/25792782#25792782)

Comment: By the way, the reason you can't case a list of derived to a list of base can be seen in the typical `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` class hierarchy.  If you have a `List<Dog>` and you casted it to a `List<Animal>`, then someone could add a `Cat` to the list (since Cats are animals too).  At that point, one of your `Dog`s would be a `Cat` and bad things would happen.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to convert `Task<Derived>` to `Task<Base>` implicitly. however you can use extension method to make conversion.

```
public static Task<TBase> ConvertToBaseTask<TDerived, TBase>(this Task<TDerived> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) 
    where TBase : class 
    where TDerived : TBase
{
    var result = task.ContinueWith(t => t.Result as TBase, cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
```