# Compiler Cannot Implicitly Convert Type - Why

Tags: c#

Why does this code compile just fine:

```
IEnumerable<Object> t = new List<Object>();
```

But this gives a compiler error:

```
Dictionary<String, IEnumerable<Object>> results = new Dictionary<String, List<object>>();
```

The Error is:

Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant; `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not. What would happen if someone did `results.Add("test", new object[1] { new object() })`? The interface says you're allowed to do that, but the underlying storage is a `List<object>`, not an `object[]`

Comment: Because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is invariant unlike `IEnumerable<T>` which is covariant

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: Eric Lippert explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792782/3094533